# Como esconder um component no emberjs 2.1 igual ao ng-hide?

Tags: javascript, emberjs

No Angular existe o `ng-hide` e o `ng-show` para exibir e esconder elementos da página. Como fazer o mesmo no EmberJS 2.1?

*Essa é uma tradução de uma pergunta minha no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548785/how-to-hide-a-component-like-ng-hide-in-emberjs-2-1).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os *components* do EmberJS tem uma *flag* `isVisible` que pode ser facilmente usada.
E tem também o css/jQuery e *flag* personalizada que pode ser usado para renderizar ou não o *component*.

A [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548923/2985195) no SOEN